# Remove Double Quotes from a String in bash

Tags: bash, git, shell

I am trying to fetch a single file from Git. When I run my git command with the hardcoded value it works. However, when I run it with a variable it breaks. I suspect it is due to double quotes being placed around my variable somehow. I have tried many commands to remove the double quotes from the string and none of them seem to work.

I am basically trying to use the filePath variable in my git command with no double quotes around it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 #reads the JSON value of the file-path key. 
 #file path key is "home/docs" (quotes included)
filePath=$(grep -o '"file-path": *"[^"]*"' ../package.json | grep -o '"[^"]*"$')
git archive --remote=git@git.SOME_URL.com:help/docs.git HEAD $filePath | tar -x
```

Comment: Stop using `grep` to parse JSON. Use a tool like `jq` that is *designed* for JSON, and knows how to produce the raw string you want. `filePath=$(jq -r '.file_path' ../package.json)`.

Comment: The last grep `grep -o '[^"]*'`. Don't include the quotes if you don't need it

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
$ printf '{"file-path": "/some/path"}' | jq --raw-output '."file-path"'
/some/path
```

So in your case:

```
filePath=$(jq --raw-output '."file-path"' ../package.json)
```

You have to quote the key because it contains a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
filePath=$(grep -o '"file-path": *"[^"]*"' ./package.json | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' "')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the problem recently that bash only removes quotes that did not result from variable expansion.  So to get bash to remove double quotes that are in a string use eval to process the string after the variable expansion:

```
foo=\"abc\"\ \"def\"
echo $foo
"abc" "def"
eval echo $foo
abc def
```

Of course, don't use eval on unsanitised strings from users, as it is susceptible to ';', '&&', etc. to execute arbitrary bash.